# Bot in a group conversations in Skype

Tags: botframework, skype

In a group conversation a bot only sees the messages that mentions the bot's name (for example, "@mybot hello!").

Is it possible to make the bot see all the messages in a Skype group chat?

Answer (score 7):

This is currently not possible. See [the documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/getting-started/#groups) on this:

> In a group the bot will only receive messages directly addressed to it e.g. “@YourBot This is the message”. It will not receive other messages sent by group participants or notifications of users joining or leaving the group.

Comment: Do you have a source for this other than your opinion?

Comment: The people at the skype developer team told me that. Also I have the experience of a skype bot with 100K users

Comment: You could flesh out this answer a bit more. At least mention in the answer where this information comes from if you don't have a source. At the very least, finish the sentence. At the moment this is a very low quality answer.

Comment: Ok, there is your reference ;)

Comment: @TheMemebot is this still the case, or is there a workaround for it?

Comment: @IneedHelp yes, it is still the case